# Error--jdk 5 or newer cannot be found on your machine

Tags: java

I have installed JDK 1.6 on my machine, but I have got the error while starting Irepor that says, "jdk 5 or newer cannot be found on your machine". I have also upgraded the version, and set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables to try to resolve the error.  Would someone kindly let me know what I'm missing to get my JDK installed?

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: also what program generates the message "JDK 5.0 or newer could not be found on machine" ?

Comment: In your development environment (Eclipse, et cetera) or what?

Comment: I am using windows 7..

Comment: I was trying to start Ireport though I have set the directory of Java home in conf file.

Comment: if you open a "DOS window" and type `java -version`, what do you get?

Comment: Does your path variable point to the java_home/bin folder? open a command prompt and type java -version and see what you get.

Comment: I get the information about the version that has been installed on the machine ,but when I run javac -version,this shows the message like "Javac is not recognized as an internal batch..........."

Comment: Yes the path variable is pointing to the directory where java is installed as I said I have already set the system variables.

Comment: maybe you are using something that expects java 32bit and you installed 64bit, or vice versa?

Comment: can you paste the output of `set PATH` and of `set JAVA_NOME` in the DOS window?

Comment: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6 and                            Path=;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6\bin\java.exe

Comment: Your path is wrong it should be `PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6\bin;%PATH%`

Comment: Nikhil,I have set the path as you suggested ,but still the error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

on command prompt type

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

does it gives the correct name of the directory where JDK is installed?

Which application is giving you this error? Is is iReport mentioned in your last post?

Comment: The command gives me the correct path of JDK. I need to have jdk to run Ireport.

Answer (score 0):

I am thankful to all of you trying to help me to resolve the error by different suggestions. Anyhow,I have solved the issue ,and I would like to share the thing that I have done.

1. As I said before the error was showing when I started Ireport, and the reason was: To start Ireport I needed to install jdk 32 bit version instead of 64 bit version. Though I have 64 bit operating system,but to initialize Ireport jdk 32 bit version was necessary.
2. I also set the environmental variables which were either not present and were not set in the system.
   2.1 Path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7\bin
   2.2 ClassPath = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7\lib (Used to find Java classes)
   2.3 Java_home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7\bin

and I have verified that the commands java -version and javac -version is running fine by installing jdk 64 bit version for 64 bit OS. 
I hope the answer would be helpful for the community.

Regards,
Ruba Mushtaq